# ERROR: ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYS.LOGOFF_TRIGGER' while compiling a package

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi i'm getting this error ERROR:
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYS.LOGOFF_TRIGGER' when tried to compile a package this error is not related to the code. can anyone help me to solve this error.

Comment: Check what trigger does.

Answer (score 1):

An administrator has (based on the name) created a database level trigger that fires every time you end your connection.  However, that trigger when it fires is encountering an error which is why your session is seeing it.

You'll need to speak your DBA to get it fixed or dropped.